# Loop with trigger (which contains animation) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops, animation

So I seem to have run into a bit of a dead end. I'm making a page which has an image slider. The slider has three images, one centered on the screen, the other two overflow on the left and right. When you click on the button to advance the slides it runs this code....

```
$('#slideRight').click(function() {
    if ($('.container').is(':animated')) {return false;}
    var next=parseInt($('.container img:last-of-type').attr('id')) + 1;
    if (next == 12) {
        next = 0;
    }
    var diff = galsize() - 700;
    if ($('.thumbs').css("left") == "0px") {
        var plus = 78;
    } else {
        var plus = 0;
    }
    var app='<img id="' + next + '" src="' + imgs[next].src + '">';
    $('.container').width('2800px').append(app);
    $('.container').animate({marginLeft: (diff + plus) + "px"}, 300, function() {
        $('.container img:first-of-type').remove();
        $('.container').width('2100px').css("margin-left", (galsize() + plus) + "px");
    });
}); // end right click
```

This works just fine, not a problem..... I also have an interval set up to run this automatically every 5 seconds to form a slideshow...

```
var slideShow = setInterval(function() {
    $('#slideRight').trigger("click");
}, 5000);
```

This also works perfectly, not a problem.... However my problem is this.... I have thumbnails, when you click on a thumbnail, it should run this code until the current picture is the same as the thumbnail.... here is the code....

```
$('img.thumbnail').click(function() {
    clearInterval(slideShow);
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    while ($('.container img:eq(1)').attr('src') != src) {
        $('#slideRight').trigger("click");
    }
});
```

When I click on the thumbnail nothing happens... I've used alert statements to try and debug, what ends up happening is this....

The while loop executes, however nothing happens the first time. The slide is not advanced at all. Starting with the second execution, the is('::animated') is triggered EVERY TIME and the remainder of the slideRight event is not executed...

So my first problem, can anyone shed some light on why it doesn't run the first time?

And my second question, is there any way to wait until the animation is complete before continuing with the loop?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to start with the second part of your question, regarding completing the animation before continuing with the loop.

I have done something similar in the past, and what I did was set two global variables to control the animation.  One variable is for how long you want the period to be, the other is a counter for how much time since the last loop.

So, for example:

```
$timeToChange = 5; // in Seconds
$timeSinceReset = 0; // also in Seconds
```

Set your interval for one second and call a new function (`autoAdvance()`):

```
var slideShow = setInterval(function() {
    autoAdvance();
}, 1000); // only one second
```

and then use the counter variable to count each time the interval is called (each second).  Something like:

```
function autoAdvance(){

    if($timeSinceReset == $timeToChange){

        $timeSinceReset = 0;

        $('#slideRight').trigger("click"); // execute click if satisfied
    }
    else{$timeSinceReset++;}

}
```

To stop from looping until the animation is done, reset `$timeSinceReset` back to 0 (zero) when you click on the thumbnail.  Something like:

```
$('#thumbnail').click(function(){
    $timeSinceReset = 0;
});
```

That'll give you a nice 5 second buffer (or whatever you set `$timeToChange`) before the loop continues.

As for the first part of your question, grab the number of the particular thumbnail, and use that to scroll to the appropriate image.  Something like:

```
$('.thumb').click(function (each) {
    $childNumber = $(this).index();
});
```

which you cansee in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Pe73/1/).  Click in one of the grey boxes and it'll tell you which one you clicked in.  Use that info to scroll to the appropriate image (1, 2 or 3 if you only have three images).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. the only problem with the two variables, is that if you click on the arrows, nothing would happen. It has three different ways to access photos, click on the left/right arrows (the #slideRight button for example), the slideshow, and the thumbnails.

Comment: I realized that after the initial post and made a small edit to it.  Instead of calling the click from the setInterval, you'll want to call a function.  Within that function you can add to $timeSinceReset, as well as check the condition.  If condition passes, execute click.  I'll edit it in the post.

Comment: I tried running it without the interval at all. the problem is the animation in the code itself....  $('.container').animate({marginLeft: (diff + plus) + "px"}, 300, function() {
        $('.container img:first-of-type').remove();
        $('.container').width('2100px').css("margin-left", (galsize() + plus) + "px");
    });

Comment: So the animation was never working?  Regardless of the thumbnails or not?  I haven't run the code to check if it was working.  I edited the answer to explain creating the custom function and using it with setInterval.

Comment: The content has a .animate() which actually slides the pictures over in a period of 300 ms. That is the animation that is blocking the code from working. Due to the precise nature of the div widths and the margins, that animation needs to complete before the content can run again.

Comment: what is `galsize()` ?

Comment: function galsize() {
        var diff = $('.gallery').width() - 2100;
        diff = (diff + 4) /2;
        return diff;
    }

Comment: In other words it figures out what the margin should be so the second picture is always centered

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full solution for one possible way of doing it at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Pe73/4/).

**HTML:**

The top container holds the images.  In this particular example I've included three, using divs instead of images.  Whether you use images or divs doesn't change anything.

```
<div class="holder_container">
    <div class="img_container">
        <div class="photo type1">ONE</div> 
        <div class="photo type2">TWO</div>
        <div class="photo type3">THREE</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`.img_container` holds all the images, and is the same width as the sum of the widths of the images.  In this case, each image (`.photo`) is 150px wide and 50px tall, so `.img_container` is 450px wide and 50px tall. `.holder_container` is the same dimensions as a single image.  When this runs, the `.holder_container` is set to hide any overflow while `.img_container` moves its position left or right.

Included also are two nav buttons (forward and back)

```
<div class="nav_buttons">
    <div class="nav back"><<<</div>
    <div class="nav forward">>>></div>
</div>
```

As well as three thumbnail images - one for each image in the top container

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

Refer to the JS Fiddle for all CSS rules.

The most important are:

```
.holder_container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img_container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 450px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

In the example, `.type1`, `.type2` and `.type3` are only used to color the image divs so you can see the animation.  They can be left out of your code.

**JavaScript:**

The javascript contains the following elements…

Variables:

```
var timeToChange = 3;   // period of the image change, in seconds
var timeSinceReset = 0; // how many seconds have passed since last image change
var currentImage = 1;   // Which image you are currently viewing
var totalImages = 3;    // How many images there are in total
```

Functions:

autoAdvance - called once every second via `setInterval`.  Counts the number of seconds since the last image change.  If the number of seconds that has passed is equal to the period, a function is called that switches the images.

```
function autoAdvance() {
    if (timeSinceReset == timeToChange) {
        timeSinceReset = 0;
        moveNext();
    } else {
        timeSinceReset++;
    }
}
```

moveNext() - moves to the next image.  If the current image is the last (`currentImage == totalImages`) then `currentImages` is set back to 1 and the first image is displayed.

```
function moveNext(){
    if(currentImage == totalImages){
        currentImage = 1;
        var newPos = 0 + 'px';      
        $('.img_container').animate({left: newPos}, 300);
    }else{
        currentImage++;
        var newPos = -((currentImage-1) * 150) + 'px'; // child numbers are zero-based  
        $('.img_container').animate({left: newPos}, 300);
    }
}
```

Rest of code:

If one of the thumbs is clicked, move to the corresponding image.

```
$('.thumb').click(function (each) {
    timeSinceReset = 0;
    var childNumber = $(this).index();
    currentImage = childNumber + 1; // child numbers are zero-based

    var newPos = -(childNumber * 150) + 'px'; // child numbers are zero-based   
    $('.img_container').animate({left: newPos}, 300);
});
```

If one of the navigation buttons is clicked, move accordingly.  If "back" is clicked, move one image backwards (or to last image if currently on first).  If "first" is clicked, move one image forwards (or to first image if currently on last).

```
$('.nav').click(function(){
    timeSinceReset = 0;
    if($(this).hasClass('back')){ // Back button
        if(currentImage == 1){
            currentImage = totalImages;
        }else{
            currentImage--;
        }
    }else{ // Forward button
        if(currentImage == totalImages){
            currentImage = 1;
        }else{
            currentImage++;
        }
    }

    var newPos = -((currentImage-1) * 150) + 'px';      
    $('.img_container').animate({left: newPos}, 300);

});
```

Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3Pe73/4/) to the fiddle example.

Comment: Thanks Birrel..... But I've decided to just write new code that does what the slideRight button does, only with multiple images rather than trigger that click even multiple times. It seems easier than trying to solve this. The problem with including all the images into the DOM from the beginning is that when it gets to the last one, it won't cycle back to the beginning, but rather slide all the way to the beginning. Thanks for all your help. I appreciate all the effort you put into this

Comment: One method you can use to eloquently move from last to first, and vice-versa, is to copy the first image and place it after the last, and copy the last image and place it before the first.  When you go from last to first, slide to the right by one image to display the copy of the first image, and then use JS to change the position of the slider to the first image.  Check out what I mean at [this](http://www.purefitnessreddeer.com) website.  Feel free to examine the JavaScript to see the details of creating it.  Hope all works out for you.